# Deleting list points that are in a certain 3D region

Tags: list-manipulation, data, boolean-computation

Hello I have a large number of data points, from which I want to remove these(between the red lines) that seem to fall onto one plane, what would be the best and easiest approach.

Also added the saved data points : [CenterHill.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z9818dn6M_ex-VYv_NHtkBzBZp3HDE6r)

The help is appreciated, thank you.

[image: ListPointPlot3D]

Comment: So actually your two red lines are two planes. Could find their equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane seems to have no slope along the x-axis, and the y slope and z translation can easily be found just by guessing and plotting:

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[data], Plot3D[3.69 + (y - 24.4) 1.6,
 {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]}, {y, Sequence @@ MinMax[data[[All, 2]]]}]]
```

[image]

Signed distances to the plane:

```
pointOnPlane = {0, 0, 3.69 + (0 - 24.4) 1.6};
normal = Coefficient[3.69 + (y - 24.4) 1.6 - z, #] & /@ {x, y, z};
dists = With[{proj = Projection[# - pointOnPlane, normal]},
           Norm[proj] Sign[proj.normal]] & /@ data;
```

Guess (or maybe use something like `Sort[Differences[Sort[dists]]][[-1]]/2`) some appropriate threshold to seperate the points near the plane from the rest:

```
types = Values[PositionIndex[Sign[Threshold[dists, 0.04]]]];

Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[data[[types[[1]]]], PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[3], Black], PlotRange -> All],
 ListPointPlot3D[data[[types[[2]]]], PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[3], Red], PlotRange -> All],
 ListPointPlot3D[data[[types[[3]]]], PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[3], Green], PlotRange -> All],
PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.Got rid of the points by using
`nData=data  
For[i = 1, i < Length[data[[types[[2]]]]] + 1, i++,
 nData= DeleteCases[nData, data[[types[[2]]]][[i]]]]  
ListPointPlot3D[nData]`